# Multi-touch co-ordinates problem iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multi-touch

I am trying to find the coordinates of both touches in a multi touch. This code throws a SIGABRT  on the line 'UITouch *touch2 = ...'. could anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSArray *touchArray = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *touch1 = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
    UITouch *touch2 = [touchArray objectAtIndex:1];
    CGPoint firstTouch = [touch1 locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint secondTouch = [touch2 locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is only one touch in the array. You should check that the array contains an index before you try to retrieve the object at that index:

```
NSUInteger count = [array count];
id obj = (count > 1)? [array objectAtIndex:1] : nil;
id obj2 = (count > 2)? [array objectAtIndex:2] : nil;
```

Comment: This point about NSArray in general is correct, however is not the case in @Conor's issue. See my answer.

Comment: No, i am not looking to check if there is a double tap. I need to find the coordinates of both fingers as they hit the screen at the same time

Comment: @Conor Taylor: They hit at the same time in human terms. In machine terms, they are a long time apart. You will need to handle the entire suite of touch methods and act accordingly at each step; there's no guarantee that, when touches begin, you will actually have more than one touch reported.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a double click event, you need to check the value of `tapCount` of each UITouch object instead of whether `touches` has two objects.

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    if (touch.tapCount==1) {
        // do something
    } else if (touch.tapCount==2) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i am not looking to check if there is a double tap. I need to find the coordinates of both fingers as they hit the screen at the same time

Comment: You need to check out touches one by one. Save state in ivars. It is not guaranteed that both touches come together.